# Use Gradle Play Publisher's version name override in Java

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-play-publisher

Gradle Play publisher lets you [override](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher#post-processing-outputs-sanitized-by-auto-resolution) the version name before publishing to the play store.

```
play {
// ...
  resolutionStrategy = "auto"
  outputProcessor { // this: ApkVariantOutput
    versionNameOverride = "$versionNameOverride.$versionCode"
}
```

}

Is it possible to use the value of `versionNameOverride` in Java Code? We display the version name in the about page of the app using the `versionName` attribute. GPP updates the `versionNameOverride` value so the play store listing shows the correct version number but the app's about page keeps showing a different version number that's based on `versionName`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `versionNameOverride` could be done like this:

```
outputProcessor { output ->
    output.versionNameOverride = output.versionNameOverride + "." + output.versionCode
    def versionPropertyFile = file "version.properties"
    def versionProperties = new Properties()
    versionProperties.setProperty('versionCode', "$output.versionCode")
    versionProperties.setProperty('versionName', output.versionNameOverride)
    versionPropertyFile.withWriter { versionProperties.store(it, "Generated by the outputProcessor for the play plugin during publishing.") }
}
```

But if you want to show the `versionName` in your app it would be easier to use

```
try {
    PackageInfo pInfo = 
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    String version = pInfo.versionName;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The reason why your app did show the wrong values might be that your app was using `BuildConfig`. But the `versionCode` and `versionName` there do not reflect what has been set through `versionNameOverride`, but those values from your build gradle.